# "Dynamic" CSS id names? How to add them to the CSS file?

Tags: css

I have DIV ids in an application that are generated dynamically, with an ID at the end. For example: `<div id="vote_score_72">`, `<div id="vote_score_73">`, `<div id="vote_score_74">` and so on.

How can I write that id in the CSS file so I can apply a style to it?

Comment: Do they need to do different things for different IDs?

Comment: Like any other ID, with a `#` sign.

... Can you please tell us what you're actually trying to do? If this is done with JavaScript, you're much better off having a class for styles common to all of them, then use the `style` property to apply item-specific styles. If all of them have the same styles, use classes (Google "CSS classes") instead.

Comment: @ceejayoz no, the same thing.
It's a Ruby on Rails application that shows different stories in the same page. Each story has a score and the score is wrapped in a DIV with the id of the story at the end.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Further to the suggestion that you should use classes for this functionality (and you *should*), you *can*, instead, use the attribute-value-begins-with selector (this may not be the formal name):

```
div[id^=vote_score] {
    color: #f00;
    /* and so on... */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rR4aT/).

---

**Edited** to add a link to the [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/)'s [compatibility tables for advanced attribute selectors](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t31).

References:

- [CSS3 Attribute-selectors, at Sitepoint.com](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors).
- [Attribute selectors, at CSS3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/)
- [Attribute Selectors, at the Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 2):

You should add a common class to all these elements and use this class in your CSS.

**Classes** are the best way to handle common style for different elements.

Comment: I see, let's say I change the id for a class. How would I write the class name in the CSS file? Like `.classname_changingnumber`

Comment: You can call the class-name anything you like, though choosing a name relevant to the contents/purpose of the `div` would make sense.

Comment: @FelipeCerda: no, the class name should be unique for all the div you want to style. Then you can refer to this class name in your CSS