# Dynamic CSS content filling

Tags: css

I know from ["Dynamic" CSS id names? How to add them to the CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028305) that you can have the following:

```
<div id="vote_score_72">

<style>
div[id^=vote_score] {
    color: #f00;
    /* and so on... */
}
</style>
```

This allows for dynamic css stanza names, but not dynamic content.

Is there a way that I can have say...

```
<div id="vote_score_fff">

<style>
div[id^=vote_score] {
    color: #(/vote_score_[.*]/);
    /* and so on... */
}
</style>
```

Where the attribute of the style element is determined by the name of the object itself? In this case, using a substring of the id of the div element, attempted to be obtained via a bastardised form of regex, to determine it's color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#color) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color),  it is clear that you can't do that using `color` css property. even in CSS3.

Hence you need to do that dynamically.

**Using JS**

```
el.style.color = "#" + el.id.match(/[^_]+$/)[0];
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbtwy/1/)

Comment: @glasnt yeah seems better... I can't think of anything else rather than for loop though :)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it with just pure CSS. But you can use JavaScript to handle this.

Comment: Could you please provide a link or an example?